# Razor Section Definition

Tags: c#, razor

I am looking at some razor layout code. I have found the following snippet:

```
@section Foo
{
    @if (@IsSectionDefined("Foo"))
    {
        @RenderSection("Foo", required: false)
    }
}
```

Wouldn't `@section Foo` define `Foo`, meaning that the if (`@IsSectionDefined("Foo")`) condition would always be true? Also, if that section is defined in another view page, wouldn't this cause a redefinition?

Basically, I don't understand why this condition is wrapped in an `@section` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out what this pattern is for: this is used in the situation where there are several layers of layouts. A section definition is scoped to the direct parent layout of a page. Therefore, to define a section that will be rendered in a higher level layout, one must pass it up the hierarchy using this construct.

Answer (score 0):

You define the Sections in a Layout file with `RenderSection("Foo");`

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I figured out:

The snipped of code doesn't hurt anything by itself.

What it says is this:

If you want to define a `@section Foo`, you have to define it in some other pages that has the current Layout page. And if you define it, you have to render it by adding `@RenderSection("ExtraContent")` in Layout page.

**In Layout Page:**

```
@section ExtraContent{
    @if (@IsSectionDefined("ExtraContent")){
        @RenderSection("ExtraContent", required: false)
    }
  }
@RenderSection("ExtraContent")
```

**In About page:**

```
@section ExtraContent{
   <p>Some extra content</p>
}
```